Jmeter how to achieve static CSV
I just want to know your insights about this kind of logic.
I have already my CSV data file with complete information / variable that I will be using all throughout the testing. Now I want to know how can I specifically select multiple rows with username information and loop those in Login API.
Example data



Username
AccessKey
Token




Test1
Data1
Token1


Test2
Data2
Token2


Test3
Data2
Token3



In User Defined Variables there is username with values of Test1,Test3. I want to run Login API for Test1 and Test3.
Basically the idea is to Read the data first for row of Test1 run all necessary API then proceed to read data of Test3 and so on.
I'm currently using while controller however can only select single username via User Define Variables. And it would be much more easier to perform testing with multiple usernames depends on the requirement given.

It is not possible to provide a comprehensive answer without seeing the structure of the CSV file and knowing what you're trying to achieve.
The options are in:

__CSVRead() function where you can decide where and when to proceed to the next row
Filtering your CSV file somewhere in setUp Thread Group with JSR223 Sampler and leaving only the rows which matching the username from the User Defined Variables


I've edited the post if that's much better to understand I want to understand first how can i make it work what are the  needed nodes and etc.
